# Trim FASTA sequences in R, before and after a certain pattern

Tags: r, fasta

I have a fasta file, that consist of 4 fasta sequences. They all consist of similar protein sequences with few mutations in it. The file is attached here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/11OKZs47wOqYRw11Akwb4zj2RRzdqSQsC/view?usp=sharing

I want to trim all of the fasta sequences with a specific pattern. I want to only select the sequences which start by "QCVN...RAAR". However, I cannot directly use the filter function because there might be mutations s in between the "QCVN...RAAR", which might not give the exact sequences. The part that is not mutated is the start "QCVN" and the end "RRAR" that stays the same across the 4 fasta sequences gathered. Thus, is it possible for to trim the sequences before the **"QCVN**"and after the **"RAAR"**?

```
>UPH85748.1 |surface glycoprotein [Severe acute respiratory syndrome coronavirus 2]
MFVFLVLLPLVSS"**QCVNLXTRTQSYTNSFTRGVYYPDKVFRSSVLHSTQDLFLPFFSNVT
WFHAIHVSGTNGTKRFDNPVLPFNDGVYFASTEKSNIIRGWIFGTTLDSKTQSLLIVNNA
TNVVIKVCEFQFCNDPFLDVYYHKNNKSWMESEFRVYSSANNCTFEYVSQPFLMDLEGKQ
GNFKNLREFVFKNIDGYFKIYSKHTPINLGRDLPQGFSALEPLVDLPIGINITRFQTLLA
LHRSYLTPGDSSSGWTAGAAAYYVGYLQPRTFLLKYNENGTITDAVDCALDPLSETKCTL
KSFTVEKGIYQTSNFRVQPTESIVRFPNITNLCPFDEVFNATRFASVYAWNRKRISNCVA
DYSVLYNLAPFFTFKCYGVSPTKLNDLCFTNVYADSFVIRGDEVXQXAPGQTGNIADYNY
KLPDDFTGCVIAWNSNKLDSKVGGNYNYLYRLFRKSNLKPFERDISTEIYQAGNKPCNGV
AGFNCYFPLRSYGFRPTYGVGHQPYRVVVLSFELLHAPATVCGPKKSTNLVKNKCVNFNF
NGLTGTGVLTESNKKFLPFQQFGRDIADTTDAVRDPQTLEILDITPCSFGGVSVITPGTN
TSNQVAVLYQGVNCTEVPVAIHADQLTPTWRVYSTGSNVFQTRAGCLIGAEYVNNSYECD
IPIGAGICASYQTQTKSHRRAR**"SVASQSIIAYTMSLGAENSVAYSNNSIAIPTNFTISVT
TEILPVSMTKTSVDCTMYICGDSTECSNLLLQYGSFCTQLKRALTGIAVEQDKNTQEVFA
QVKQIYKTPPIKYFGGFNFSQILPDPSKPSKRSFIEDLLFNKVTLADAGFIKQYGDCLGD
IAARDLICAQKFNGLTVLPPLLTDEMIAQYTSALLAGTITSGWTFGAGAALQIPFAMQMA
YRFNGIGVTQNVLYENQKLIANQFNSAIGKIQDSLSSTASALGKLQDVVNHNAQALNTLV
KQLSSKFGAISSVLNDILSRLDKVEAEVQIDRLITGRLQSLQTYVTQQLIRAAEIRASAN
LAATKMSECVLGQSKRVDFCGKGYHLMSFPQSAPHGVVFLHVTYVPAQEKNFTTAPAICH
DGKAHFPREGVFVSNGTHWFVTQRNFYEPQIITTDNTFVSGNCDVVIGIVNNTVYDPLQP
ELDSFKEELDKYFKNHTSPDVDLGDISGINASVVNIQKEIDRLNEVAKNLNESLIDLQEL
GKYEQYIKWPWYIWLGFIAGLIAIVMVTIMLCCMTSCCSCLKGCCSCGSCCKFDEDDSEP
VLKGVKLHYT
```

Here are the codes that I tried to use to read the FASTA file

```
# Load the Biostrings package
library(Biostrings)

# Read the FASTA file
fasta <-readAAStringSet("sequences-2.fasta")
print(fasta)
```

It gives out this result

```
AAStringSet object of length 4:
    width seq                                                                                              names               
[1]  1270 MFVFLVLLPLVSSQCVNLXTRTQSYTNSFTRGVYYPDKVFRSSVLHS...VMVTIMLCCMTSCCSCLKGCCSCGSCCKFDEDDSEPVLKGVKLHYT UPH85748.1 |surfa...
[2]  1270 MFVFLVLLPLVSSQCVNLITRTQSYTNSFTRGVYYPDKVFRSSVLHS...VMVTIMLCCMTSCCSCLKGCCSCGSCCKFDEDDSEPVLKGVKLHYT UUT03046.1 |surfa...
[3]  1270 MFVFLVLLPLVSSQCVNLRTRTQSYTNSFTRGVYYPDKVFRSSVLHS...VMVTIMLCCMTSCCSCLKGCCSCGSCCKFDEDDSEPVLKGVKLHYT UYE44393.1 |surfa...
[4]  1271 MFVFLVLLPLVSSQCVNFRTRTQLPPAYTNSFTRGVYYPDKVFRSSV...VMVTIMLCCMTSCCSCLKGCCSCGSCCKFDEDDSEPVLKGVKLHYT UYW62681.1 |surfa...
```

Then I tried to use this code to trim the sequences before "QCVN"

```
# Loop through the sequences and trim the pattern
for (i in 1:length(fasta)) {
  sequence <- as.character(fasta[[i]]) # convert the sequence to a character string
  sequence <- gsub(paste("^.*", stop_pattern), stop_pattern, sequence) # remove everything that comes before the pattern
  fasta[[i]] <- AAString(sequence) # convert the trimmed sequence back to a AAString object
}

# Write the trimmed sequences to a new FASTA file
writeXStringSet(fasta, "file.fasta")
```

But it didnt work, as it didn't trim anything from the sequences.
Is there any possible way to trim the sequences before the **"QCVN**"and after the **"RAAR"**?

Comment: Since you're using Biostrings, look at the documentation for `trimLRPatterns()` and `matchLRPatterns()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use just one `gsub` for both. You can keep the middle part if it matches the group `.*(pattern).*` as it is saved to `\\1`

```
example <- "somethingbadQCVNsomethingelsebutgoodRAARsomethingbad"

gsub(".*(QCVN.*RAAR).*", "\\1", example)
```

Result

```
[1] "QCVNsomethingelsebutgoodRAAR"
```

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55921638/gsub-replacing-string-with-pattern-matching-code-and-not-specific-string-variabl) question for more details